# How do I add a different scale to a line graph and still make it look normal?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I am listing out page views for different web pages on a dashboard, and this is how it looks.

The horizontal scale is weekly, going back one year and the number corresponding to each graph is the cumulative views for the last week.
[image]

The graph truncates to the end of last week.

The overall scale of the graph was made weekly because daily granularity created too much noise and wasn’t really useful.

So what’s missing here is the current week. Despite the graph scale being weekly, it's important to have the last six days of the current week shown because page views metrics is something I want to track very closely for variation. For example, if the trend shows that it's going down, double down to fix it. In the above image, I am very interested in the graph where the red arrow is pointing to. I will spend time analyzing why it is growing.

So the question is:
Can I can append a daily scale graph to a weekly one without making it look weird (accounting for the difference in Y scale and other factors). Are there any examples like this in the stats world?

Answer (score 1):

Can it be just a simple moving average (MA) filter?

${x_{k} = \frac{1}{7}\sum_{i=0}^{6}x_{k-i}}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this, but I would just append another graph of the last 6 days. Indicate the new portion via color on the curve and label the change in the horizontal scale, with an additional vertical scale on the right hand side (probably the original scale *7 to try to match).

I'm honestly not sure if this is an appropriate statistical graph, but your need is a reasonable one and this could address it.